# Docker build image - glob error { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir

Tags: unix, docker, dockerfile, webpack-2

I'm attempting to build a Docker image of a React+TypeScript+NodeJS application built with Webpack 2.0, but I get the following error

```
> frontend@0.0.1 build /
> webpack -p --config configs/webpack.config.ts --env.build --env.sourceMap

{ isDev: false }
glob error { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir '/proc/1/map_files/55836c87b000-55836c897000'
  errno: -1,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: '/proc/1/map_files/55836c87b000-55836c897000' }
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir '/proc/1/map_files/55836c87b000-55836c897000'
```

after running the following command

```
docker build -t frontend .
```

My package.json looks like this

```
"scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf build",
    "build": "webpack -p --config configs/webpack.config.ts --env.build --env.sourceMap",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --config configs/webpack.config.ts",
    "dev:open": "webpack-dev-server --config configs/webpack.config.ts --open",
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json && echo \"running stylelint\" &&./node_modules/stylelint/bin/stylelint.js \"src/**/*.scss\"",
    "tsc": "tsc -p .",
    "tsc:watch": "tsc -p . --noEmit -w",
    "test": "jest --config jest.json",
    "reinstall": "rm -rf node_modules && npm install",
    "precommit": "npm run lint",
    "prepush": "npm run lint & npm run tsc & npm run test",
    "organize": "npm prune && npm dedupe && npm shrinkwrap --dev",
    "deploy": "npm run build && npm run serve",
    "serve": "NODE_ENV=production node server.ts"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "fsevents": "*"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^8.0.51",
    "@types/prop-types": "^15.5.2",
    "@types/react": "^16.0.22",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.3",
    "@types/react-hot-loader": "^3.0.5",
    "@types/react-redux": "^5.0.12",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.2.1",
    "@types/react-router-redux": "^5.0.10",
    "@types/redux": "^3.6.31",
    "@types/webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "@types/webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.2",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.6.1",
    "react": "^16.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "stylelint": "^8.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^17.0.0",
    "stylelint-webpack-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "ts-loader": "^3.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
    "tslib": "^1.8.0",
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "tslint-react": "^3.2.0",
    "typescript": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.0.4",
    "@types/chai-as-promised": "7.1.0",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.1.4",
    "@types/jest": "^21.1.6",
    "babel-jest": "^21.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.4",
    "enzyme": "^3.1.1",
    "husky": "^0.14.3",
    "jest": "^21.2.1",
    "jest-cli": "^21.2.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.1.0",
    "ts-jest": "^21.2.1"
  }
```

and my webpack.config.ts looks like this

```
const filePath = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const StyleLintPlugin = require('stylelint-webpack-plugin');

const PATHS = {
  root: filePath.resolve(__dirname, '..'),
  nodeModules: filePath.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules'),
  src: filePath.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
  build: filePath.resolve(__dirname, '../build'),
  style: filePath.resolve(__dirname, '../src/style'),
  images: filePath.resolve(__dirname, '../src/images')
};

const DEV_SERVER = {
  historyApiFallback: true,
  overlay: true,
  stats: {
    providedExports: false,
    chunks: false,
    hash: false,
    version: false,
    modules: false,
    reasons: false,
    children: false,
    source: false,
    errors: true,
    errorDetails: true,
    warnings: false,
    publicPath: false
  }
};

interface env {
  build?: string;
  sourceMap?: string;
  awesome?: string;
}

module.exports = (env: env = {}) => {
  const isBuild = !!env.build;
  const isDev = !env.build;
  const isSourceMap = !!env.sourceMap || isDev;
  console.log({ isDev });

  return {
    cache: true,
    devtool: isDev ? 'eval-source-map' : 'source-map',
    devServer: DEV_SERVER,

    context: PATHS.root,

    entry: {
      app: [
        './src/index.tsx',
      ],
    },
    output: {
      path: PATHS.build,
      filename: isDev ? '[name].js' : '[name].[hash].js',
      publicPath: '/',
    },

    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
      modules: ['src', 'node_modules'],
    },

    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          include: PATHS.src,
          loader: (env.awesome ?
              [
                {
                  loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                  options: {
                    transpileOnly: true,
                    useTranspileModule: false,
                    sourceMap: isSourceMap,
                  },
                },
              ] : [
                {
                  loader: 'ts-loader',
                  options: {
                    transpileOnly: true,
                    compilerOptions: {
                      'sourceMap': isSourceMap,
                      'target': isDev ? 'es2015' : 'es5',
                      'isolatedModules': true,
                      'noEmitOnError': false,
                    },
                  },
                },
              ]
          ),
        },
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['env']
            }
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.json$/,
          include: [PATHS.src],
          loader: { loader: 'json-loader' },
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            use: 'css-loader'
          })
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallback: "style-loader",
            use: "css-loader!sass-loader",
          }),
        },
        {
          test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|ico)$/i,
          loaders: [
            'file-loader?hash=sha512&limit=1000&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
            'image-webpack-loader?bypassOnDebug&optipng.optimizationLevel=7&gifsicle.interlaced=false'
          ]
        }
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      StyleLintPlugin(),
      new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css'),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
          NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(isDev ? 'development' : 'production'),
        },
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'vendor',
        minChunks: (module: any) => module.context && module.context.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1,
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'manifest',
      }),
      ...(isDev ? [
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
      ] : []),
      ...(isBuild ? [
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
          minimize: true,
          debug: false
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
          beautify: false,
          compress: {
            screw_ie8: true,
            warnings: false
          },
          comments: false,
          sourceMap: isSourceMap,
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: './index.html',
        }),
      ] : []),
    ],
    stats: {
      providedExports: false,
      chunks: false,
      hash: false,
      version: false,
      timings: false,
      modules: false,
      reasons: true,
      children: false,
      source: false,
      warnings: true,
      publicPath: false
    },
    performance: {
      hints: "warning"
    }
  };
};
```

and my Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM node:latest

COPY package.json package.json
COPY npm-shrinkwrap.json npm-shrinkwrap.json
RUN npm install --production
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080

RUN npm run deploy
```

and finally I have a .dockerignore

```
Dockerfile
.dockerignore
.gitignore
README.md
build
node_modules
```

As far as I can tell this is a permissions issue. Is there something I can do to change permissions? I'm not even sure what process fails.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `map_files` directory is a representation of the files a process currently has memory mapped by the kernel. This info is also contained in the `maps` file in the same directory.

As these files are a representation of memory, they change frequently. If a process creates a directory listing and then processes the list, the files might not exist by the time the process gets to them.

If the build is reporting files in `/proc`, a search has likely  started from the `/` directory in the container and is recursively searching everything on the filesystem.

Use a directory other than `/` as the `WORKDIR` in your `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json npm-shrinkwrap.json /app/
RUN npm install --production
COPY . /app/
EXPOSE 8080

RUN npm run deploy
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also get this exact error if you accidentally hit Deny when OSX asks if you want to allow Docker to update files on your computer. For some reason, factory resetting docker and uninstalling/re-installing does not cause the prompt for these permissions to appear again.

I was able to fix the error by following these [steps](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/control-access-to-files-and-folders-on-mac-mchld5a35146/mac) to grant Docker permissions to Documents where my code was stored.