# nodejs api running within container can not connect to server

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, npm, rest

I have an api app build with nodejs which connect to a remote PostGresql database. It is working okay when running it using npm.

I tried to build this api as docker image and run it. After running this same api app inside a docker container, the api app can no longer communicate with the PostgreSQL database.

**ENV**

- Mac 10.15.7
- Docker 19.03.13

**TRIED**

- `docker run -p 8080:3000 <image>`
- `docker run -p 80:3000 --network="host" <image>`

**CONSOLE**

```
> nsm-api@0.0.1 start:dev /
> nodemon --config nodemon.json

[nodemon] 2.0.6
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): src/**/*
[nodemon] watching extensions: ts
[nodemon] starting `TZ=utc node --inspect=127.0.0.1:9223 -r ts-node/register -- src/main.ts`
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9223/a8f5022e-be72-43ac-b1f7-b0487aaf370b
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
[Nest] 41   - 11/26/2020, 7:56:44 AM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 41   - 11/26/2020, 7:56:44 AM   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +145ms
[Nest] 41   - 11/26/2020, 7:56:44 AM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 41   - 11/26/2020, 7:56:44 AM   [InstanceLoader] MailerModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 41   - 11/26/2020, 7:56:44 AM   [InstanceLoader] HttpModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 41   - 11/26/2020, 7:56:44 AM   [InstanceLoader] MailerCoreModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 41   - 11/26/2020, 7:56:46 AM   [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)... +1979ms
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir '/proc/1/map_files/559c210e0000-559c216d0000'
    at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:790:3)
    at GlobSync._readdir (/node_modules/glob/sync.js:288:41)
    at GlobSync._readdirInGlobStar (/node_modules/glob/sync.js:267:20)
    at GlobSync._readdir (/node_modules/glob/sync.js:276:17)
    at GlobSync._processReaddir (/node_modules/glob/sync.js:137:22)
    at GlobSync._process (/node_modules/glob/sync.js:132:10)
    at GlobSync._processGlobStar (/node_modules/glob/sync.js:380:10)
    at GlobSync._process (/node_modules/glob/sync.js:130:10)
    at GlobSync._processGlobStar (/node_modules/glob/sync.js:383:10)
    at GlobSync._process (/node_modules/glob/sync.js:130:10)
^Cnpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 143
npm ERR! nsm-api@0.0.1 start:dev: `nodemon --config nodemon.json`
npm ERR! Exit status 143
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the nsm-api@0.0.1 start:dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-11-26T07_56_50_252Z-debug.log
```

**Dockerfile**

```
# Use the official image as a parent image.
FROM node:10-alpine

# Set the working directory.
WORKDIR .

# Copy the file from your host to your current location.
COPY package.json .

# Run the command inside your image filesystem.
RUN npm install

# Add metadata to the image to describe which port the container is listening on at runtime.
EXPOSE 3000

# Run the specified command within the container.
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:dev" ]

# Copy the rest of your app's source code from your host to your image filesystem.
COPY . .
```

**Database Connection**

I use a .env file to add database credentials and host so that the app can use to connect.

```
POSTGRES_HOST=****
POSTGRES_PORT=***
POSTGRES_USER=****
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=****
POSTGRES_DATABASE=postgres
PORT=3000
MODE=PROD
RUN_MIGRATIONS=true
SECRET_KEY=scretkey
```

---

**Edit:** I have also tried with the `sudo` command, but that did not help.

Comment: Are you listening on `127.0.0.1` inside the container? then it must be `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Thanks for reply, for default network, I am using bridge networks with
` "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
  "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",`
For network is host, I am using 
` "Gateway": "",
"IPAddress": "",'

Comment: Make a `netstat -ln` on the host, and see if the port is present for either ip4 or ip6.

Comment: @FrankNielsen after ran docker and exec into it, I was able to ping the remote host. My guess is that the networking was okay. The problem here is that typeorm is scanning for directory `Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir`. This operation is not allow because docker is not sudo.

Comment: The answer here helps me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47382957/docker-build-image-glob-error-error-eperm-operation-not-permitted-scandir